# HelloWorld not reading event from STDIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I want to get the SAM CLI to read an event from standard in.

From [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html) I should be able to:

`sam local generate-event s3 [put/delete] --bucket <bucket> --key <key> | sam local invoke <function logical id>`

This implies that I should be able to invoke my lambda from the command line by piping an event into the STDIN for `sam local invoke`

Well, take this for example:

```sh
# CREATE A HELLO_WORLD SAM PROJECT
sam init \
  --no-interactive \
  --name sam-read-stdin \
  --runtime python3.7 \
  --dependency-manager pip \
  --app-template hello-world

cd sam-read-stdin

# FORCE THE LAMBDA TO PRINT THE EVENT
sed 's/#     raise e/print\("EVENT %s" % event\)/' -i hello_world/app.py

# BUILD INSIDE DOCKER CONTAINER
sam build --use-container

# INVOKE USING THE STDIN PIPE
sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy | \
  sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction

# ALWAYS PRINTS THIS RESULT
# EVENT {}
```

What do I need to do so that the printout `EVENT {}` is instead from `sam local generate-event`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With release 31 of aws-sam they changed the syntax for reading an event from stdin. You now need to do it like this:

```
sam local generate-event s3 [put/delete] --bucket <bucket> --key <key> | sam local invoke <function logical id> -e -
```

Notice the "-e -" at the end.

See
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v0.31.0

Comment: Confirmed this modification to my example works: `sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy |   sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction -e -` THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

One "solution" is to just add an extra intermediary step of using the `-e <event.json>`:

```sh
sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy > test-event.json

sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction -e test-event.json

rm test-event.json

# THIS WORKS THE WAY I WANT STDIN TO WORK
# EVENT {'body': 'eyJ0ZXN0IjoiYm9keSJ9', 'resource':...
```